# Is there a straight forward way to add sparklines overlays to an image in Matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, sparklines

I have an image.

I have several small functions of attributes of that image, that I'd like to overlay like a [spark line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparkline) into the image.  Is there a straight forward way to do this?

Obviously, I could write my own graphing routines, to generate rasterized graphics objects, and overlay them on the image.  I was hoping for something a bit more straight forward.

Here's what I'm looking for (roughly)

```
I = imread('cameraman.tif');
imshow(I);
figure(2);
plot(I(128,:));
* insert some magic here *
```

and generate output like the below.  In this case, I'm plotting the grayscale values across the middle of the image.  In general, I'll want to be able to put the sparkline plot anywhere in the image, with any orientation.  But, this is getting generally to what I'm interested in achieving.

[image]

Comment: Don’t create a new figure or new axes. You can plot in the same axes that contain the image. Just do `hold on` after displaying the image, before `plot`ting your sparkline. Add a value to the data to control the vertical location.

Comment: @CrisLuengo in hind sight that seems obvious.  To deal with rotations etc, there's a bit more work, but nothing especially onerous...  Write that up as an answer!